# How to reset the state value in setState based on its previous value

Tags: reactjs

I have a timer and the value of the timer depends on the value of the button that is clicked. I put the setState on the componentDidUpdate so whenever it updates the value of the state will decrement by 1. I have 3 buttons for the timerValue.

```
1st button value is 5, 2nd button value is 10, 3rd button value is 15
```

The problem is I want to reset the value of the state depends on the button that I've clicked, for example I clicked 5 when the timer turns to 0 I want it to return to the previous value of the state which is 5.

This is my code

```
this.state = {
timerValue: 0,
}
```

The timerValue depends on the button that I clicked.

this is the code for condition and setState

```
 if(timerValue<1) {
    this.setState({ timerValue, })
 }
```

What I want to happen is reset the value of timerValue depends on the value of the button whenever it turns to 0.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Use a set state callback to access previous state.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  timerValue: timerValue === 0 ? prevState.timerValue : timerValue
}))
```

Comment: It didn't work, is there any other way to reset the value?